# IndexedDB using YDN-DB: What is the most efficient way to retrieve the highest Primary Key value?

Tags: indexeddb, ydn-db

While building an offline app using YDN-DB wrapper for IndexedDB, I now need to query any object store for the highest `Integer` primary key value in the store. By extension, I can then predict and use the next autoIncrement number, even before running the next `INSERT`.
Presently I can think of the following approach:

```
db.values('store_name').done(function (recordset) {
   //run through the key/value pairs in recordset until I arrive at the 
         highest value.
});
```

Or perhaps:

```
db.from('store_name').select('primary_key').order('primary_key', true).list(1)
.done(function(value) {
  //use value for some task;
});
```

Is there a more efficient way?
And while we're on it, the `"primary_key"` argument specified in `.order('primary_key', true)` seems superfluous to me, since this ordering would normally be by primary key. If that is right, what's the syntax to skip it?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

While waiting, I realized that, in fact, with the `.order('primary_key', true)`, the second parameter of `true`(==reverse) wast totally ignored by the query engine. But the below form came to the rescue:

```
db.from('store_name').select('primary_key').reverse().list(1)
    .done(function(highest){
        console.log(highest);
```

});

While this seems to be a little sleeker, I still crave an endorsement from the 'profs'.

Thank you.

Comment: Update API doc for `order` not supporting second argument, direction. It is confusing if there was previous order direction. `reverse` method is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common operation. I will use

```
db.keys('store_name', null, 1, 0, true)
```

Using query module `db.from` is wrapper to above method. Sorry for regression on `order` ignoring direction. I will fix. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have been studying the `db.keys()` syntax you suggested. Trying to understand all its arguments and usage, before deciding I how best I can use it. Right now I'm here: http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/schema.html. Anywhere else you can direct me?